# Log4j 2.15 cannot load plugins from packages declared in configuration of log4j2.xml

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm currently migrating to log4j2 and in order to achieve a specific custom based logging, have created a custom trigerring policy using the source code of existing trigerring policies and have packaged the same plugin in the project jar(It's a spring mvc project). But the plugin is not getting loaded from the packages mentioned in configuration of log4j2.xml. (But the same was working in the sample java project used for testing)

In catalina.out -> Error: localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Took 0.003641 seconds to load 0 plugins from package com.test.abc.customTriggeringPolicy

In log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration name="abc" status="trace" packages="com.test.abc.customTriggeringPolicy" verbose="true">
```

....

So, is there anyway to resolve this issue? or am i missing any configuration?

Comment: Did you configure the annotation processor at compile time? https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/plugins.html

Comment: Have declared in configuration of log4j2.xml , like this :<Configuration name="abc" status="trace" packages="com.test.abc.customTriggeringPolicy" verbose="true">

Comment: note of caution: 2.15 has 2 serious security vulnerabilities in it. You should really be using no version earlier than 2.17

Comment: Ok, will check and update to 2.17 then